# Find out mouse button state via Xlib in Python

Tags: python, linux, xlib, mouse-cursor

I can determine the current mouse pointer position with:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
display = Display()
qp = display.screen().root.query_pointer()
print(qp.root_x, qp.root_y)
```

How do I get the current mouse button states like left/right button pressed/released via `Xlib`, too? (Or if this is not possible - why not?)

Answer (score 1):

If the X server has the RECORD extension enabled, it can be used to find out the current mouse button state. However, it won't provide the information directly: The individual button up and down events have to be tracked.

This also means that the current state will only be known, once the program has received at least one first event on mouse button up or down.

`python-xlib` provides the following example script at https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/master/examples/record_demo.py

> ```
> from __future__ import print_function
>
> import sys
> import os
>
> # Change path so we find Xlib
> sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
>
> from Xlib import X, XK, display
> from Xlib.ext import record
> from Xlib.protocol import rq
>
> local_dpy = display.Display()
> record_dpy = display.Display()
>
>
> def lookup_keysym(keysym):
>     for name in dir(XK):
>         if name[:3] == "XK_" and getattr(XK, name) == keysym:
>             return name[3:]
>     return "[%d]" % keysym
>
>
> def record_callback(reply):
>     if reply.category != record.FromServer:
>         return
>     if reply.client_swapped:
>         print("* received swapped protocol data, cowardly ignored")
>         return
>     if not len(reply.data) or reply.data[0] < 2:
>         # not an event
>         return
>
>     data = reply.data
>     while len(data):
>         event, data = rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(
>             data, record_dpy.display, None, None)
>
>         if event.type in [X.KeyPress, X.KeyRelease]:
>             pr = event.type == X.KeyPress and "Press" or "Release"
>
>             keysym = local_dpy.keycode_to_keysym(event.detail, 0)
>             if not keysym:
>                 print("KeyCode%s" % pr, event.detail)
>             else:
>                 print("KeyStr%s" % pr, lookup_keysym(keysym))
>
>             if event.type == X.KeyPress and keysym == XK.XK_Escape:
>                 local_dpy.record_disable_context(ctx)
>                 local_dpy.flush()
>                 return
>         elif event.type == X.ButtonPress:
>             print("ButtonPress", event.detail)
>         elif event.type == X.ButtonRelease:
>             print("ButtonRelease", event.detail)
>         elif event.type == X.MotionNotify:
>             print("MotionNotify", event.root_x, event.root_y)
>
>
> # Check if the extension is present
> if not record_dpy.has_extension("RECORD"):
>     print("RECORD extension not found")
>     sys.exit(1)
> r = record_dpy.record_get_version(0, 0)
> print("RECORD extension version %d.%d" % (r.major_version, r.minor_version))
>
> # Create a recording context; we only want key and mouse events
> ctx = record_dpy.record_create_context(
>     0,
>     [record.AllClients],
>     [{
>         'core_requests': (0, 0),
>         'core_replies': (0, 0),
>         'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
>         'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
>         'delivered_events': (0, 0),
>         'device_events': (X.KeyPress, X.MotionNotify),
>         'errors': (0, 0),
>         'client_started': False,
>         'client_died': False,
>     }])
>
> # Enable the context; this only returns after a call to record_disable_context,
> # while calling the callback function in the meantime
> record_dpy.record_enable_context(ctx, record_callback)
>
> # Finally free the context
> record_dpy.record_free_context(ctx)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your X window must support XInput extension. Real X works but getting to mouse button doesn't work if the X server doesn't support the extension like VNC server.

If the X server supports it, then you can get to the mouse state as follows:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.ext import xinput

display = Display()

import time

while True:
    buttons = []

    for device_info in display.xinput_query_device(xinput.AllDevices).devices:
        if not device_info.enabled:
            continue
        if xinput.ButtonClass not in [ device_class.type for device_class in device_info.classes ]:
            continue
        buttons.append(device_info)

    for button in buttons:
        for device_class in button.classes:
            if xinput.ButtonClass == device_class.type:
                if device_class.state[0]:
                    print('Device {name} - Primary button down'.format(name=button.name))
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm not 100% sure as the docs are not found anywhere, but I'm pretty sure device_class.state[0] is primary (left button), 1 is middle, and 2 is right button.

You can probably find out [the button number assignment spec here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/inputproto/XI2proto.txt)

EDIT:

Why there are two for loops - First I wrote the "buttons" part outside of forever loop. But, "hey, you can plug in mouse any time."

You'll find that, there are many devices including "virtual" ones. On laptop, touchpad does work as button too so in your app, if you want to know the real mouse's buttons, you may have to pick a device from name. Again, there is no good docs so you probably have to decipher the device class object. You can find the xinput as /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/ext/xinput.py. (Adjust it accordingly if you are using Python2.) Good luck.

Comment: You can get the button up/down events and that means you have to keep the scoreboard by yourself. This would not be impossible but it's error prone. It probably depends on your application - if you don't need to keep track of mouse button without precise timing, that would be okay. The nature of X is based on event, and scanning static state of button requires the ext, as well as fast connection between the x server and client (your python). If it's on same host, works. Remote connection - you prob. have to deal with the latency of shuttling the req/answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me :) And those events would best be accessed via the RECORD extension from the other answer?

Comment: Also, I think I agree with you, most of X seems based on events. And this applies to mouse pointer position, too, no? At least, there are mouse pointer motion events. However, mouse pointer position can be acquired very easily with the commands from the example from the question text. So that's why I thought, there might be another set of simple commands to acquire mouse button state, too. I hope I didn't make that too confusing. ;)